# Kohana 3.1 ORM: How to make 'where ... in' clause

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

Thanks to Kohana's excellent documentation, I'm having to resort to prostrate myself on SO. ;)

Hopefully this is really simple: I'm trying to gather all stories which belong to a certain group of IDs.  My code is as follows:

```
$story_ids = '(12,56,99,213,319)';
$stories = ORM::factory('story')->where('id', 'IN', $story_ids)->find_all();
```

However, this is obviously not working. I'm getting a MySQL error because single-quotes are being put around the `$story_ids` string in the query.

**EDIT:** I've also tried passing `$story_ids` as an array, but then I just get a "500 Internal Server Error"

Is it possible to do what I'm asking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you perhaps forget the **->select()**  ?

Also, here are two ways outlined [here](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/6091/orm-how-to-select-2-tables-with-in-clauses/p1) to use the "IN" keyword:

```
ORM::factory('table1')->select('mls_id')->where('mls_id', 'NOT IN', DB::Select('mls_id')->from('table2'))->find_all();
ORM::factory('table1')->select('mls_id')->where('mls_id', 'NOT IN', DB::Expr('(SELECT mls_id FROM table2)'))->find_all();
```

I typically use the DB::Expr method with what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not performing a subquery though. I already have the string (or array) of IDs and want to just pass that into the third parameter of the where method.

If I used DB::Expr(), would it just be a matter of:  
ORM::factory('story')->where('id', 'IN', DB::Expr($story_ids))->find_all();?

Comment: Well slap my pooper and call me Charlie, it worked!
Wrapping my $story_ids string in the DB::Expr() solved the problem.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Passing $story_ids as an array should work.

```
$story_ids = array(12,56,99,213,319);
$stories = ORM::factory('story')->where('id', 'IN', $story_ids)->find_all();
```

What Kohana version do you use?

Comment: It's in the title, but I'm using 3.1.1, to be more specific. Passing the values as an array returns a 500 error, as stated in my decription. `DB::Expr` works perfectly for me, so I've been using that. :)